# How to convert pressure limit in 3D to 2D?

Tags: pressure

Sorry of this question is super general, but how would you convert between a 3D pressure limit in $N/m^2$ to a 2D pressure limit in $N/m$ if the boundary is arbitrarily thin?
I've heard before that you multiply the pressure limit by the "width" of the boundary, but what about in this case? Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual application here? Are you trying to run a simulation or use a 2D model?  Or are you doing something else?

Comment: I'm trying to test how well a network of polymers would stop the expansion of a balloon, but I only know the individual spring constants of the fibers. I'm not sure how to do that so I'm starting in 2D with a single strand and like a "slice" of the balloon. So like how would compression stress as a result of a network in 3D best be modeled in 2D as a simple first pass, or is that not feasible? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer to another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163903/how-do-we-define-capillary-number-in-2d-two-dimensions/163909#163909) about how to define things in 2D vs 3D. It's the same answer I would give here I think, although I'm not sure I understand your use-case exactly... but I think my advice would be the same.

Comment: Yes this really helped! Sorry I didn't see it before, but thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: No worries! I'll go ahead and close this question as a duplicate of that one then. Good luck, and I hope to see more questions and answers from you soon!